# Conversion to Swift 5 is available

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I'm getting this warning in Xcode 10.2:

> Conversion to Swift 5 is available

[image]

When I click this error, it's opening this window:

[image]

When we click **Next** what will happen?

Comment: code will converted to latest swift version, i think

Comment: when you convert or press next then in you projet all libraries updated to support 5.0 id available. or all targets are converts to the 5.0

Comment: Your all old syntax will be converted to swift5 version, XCode will show the list of files with changes. Make sure you back up your project before do that

Comment: @ Prashant Tukadiya, if it converted into Swift 5.0 , when i run in iOS old versions like iOS 9.0, can it work.

Comment: @Sagar Bhut, if it converted into Swift 5.0 , when i run in iOS old versions like iOS 9.0, can it work.

Comment: yes if your library you use that provide supports.

Comment: @ Sagar Bhut, thank you....

Comment: @iOS Yes for iOS 9 It should work. latest version of swift (swift 5) doesn't remove support for old iOS version of APIs, but  it  will add new APIs  support latest OS (iOS 12)

Comment: @ Prashant Tukadiya, thank you.\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the current version of swift is swift5 which is only supported in Xcode 10.2 and you are using another version like swift4 or swift4.2 in xcode 10.2.  This warning means that a new version of Swift is available if you click this warning you will receive a pop up and will ask for permission to convert your code to latest version of swift (which is now swift5). if you click yes to the pop up Xcode automatically convert your code to newest version of swift(which is swift5 in your case)

Comment: thank you. Is it can run lower versions is iOS like iOS8.0 and iOS 9.0 automatically when submit into app store.

Comment: yes you can run on all versions