# keep on loading when i convert swift 4.2 to swift 5 in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode11

I try to convert swift 4.2 to swift 5 using the Xcode converter. In this converter, selected all the target and submit on there.

My problem is it's taking more time and it keeps on loading more than 2 hours.

[image]

can you please help me how do solve this and convert my project to swift 5.thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55790040/10584330 , Please cancel now and before convert make sure your Xcode version.

Comment: Thanks, @AnjaliShah. But I have Xcode 11(Mojava osx latest)version. I tried too many times close and open. Even it keeps on loading.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the exclamation mark and the Indexing at the top. Your project hasn’t finished indexing, and it doesn’t compile. It must do both, before you use the converter.